How to make vite lib mode output into separate files
I'm using vite's lib mode to generate my vue3 library which is used in another project. But it builds all content into one js file. I hope it could build all contents into separate files according to folder structure.
My vite options:
{
   build: {
        lib: {
          entry: './src/index.ts',
          formats: ['es'],
          fileName: 'index'
        },
        cssTarget: 'chrome61',
        rollupOptions: {
          external: Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies)
        }
      },
   ...
}


Does this answer your question? How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs in rollup.js?
